# How to configure comet (comet.ml) to track Keras?

Tags: python, keras, comet, comet-ml

im trying to setup https://www.comet.ml to log my experiment details

getting strange error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 7, in <module>
    from comet_ml import Experiment
ImportError: No module named comet_ml
```

trying in python 2 and python3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like comet isn't installed on your machine.

you can use :

```
pip3 install comet_ml
pip install comet_ml
```

take a look at the example projects at:

https://github.com/comet-ml/comet-quickstart-guide